# Sinon stub method withArgs matching specific object keys

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I have a method:

```
const validate = ({ foo, bar }) => foo && bar
```

Essentially, as long as you pass an object with a `foo` and a `bar` key set, the method return `true`

Trying to stub this and struggling to see how to do so:

```
validate: stub().withArgs(???).returns(true)
```

I want to pass different data (different asserts) into the `validate` stub and have it only return true if both `foo` and `bar` keys are set in the passed in object...

For example:

```
t.is(validate({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }), true)
t.is(validate({ foo: 'foo' }), false)
```

Comment: Hm, would something like this work for you?: `validate: (withArgs, expected) => stub().withArgs(withArgs).returns(expected)` and then `t.is(validate({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }, true)(), true); ` (note second () operator to call actual stub). Which basically is the factory-like method which creates a stub with expected returned value given arguments

Comment: In the example you give, you don't need to stub validate at all--your `t.is...` statements would work find with your non-stubbed `validate` function.  _Do you have other assertions you want to run that will use the Sinon API properties?_  Like `t.is(validate.calledTwice, true)`?